# Protect download path with PHP Sessions/Cookies?

Tags: php, cookies, session-cookies

I need to ensure that a person has been to, and filled out, a registration form before going to the product download page. Right now I submit the form via ajax and if the returned JSON = success I redirect to the appropriate download page accordingly. I would like to protect the download page from direct access, to ensure we capture the lead first. I know that PHP sessions and cookies can be manipulated but it fits our needs, I am aware of the consequences etc and just need to make this work.

So on page 'http://www.example/register.php' I want to set and hash a cookie based on the current time:

```
<php 
    $time = ('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    //set a new cookie with this value and hash it
?>
```

Then on http://www.example.com/download.php check for the cookie, if it is set AND set within the last hour display the download content, if it isn't set or has expired, redirect back to the register page

```
<php
    if !$cookie or expred {
        location('http://www.example.com/register.php');
        die();
    } else {
      //download content
    }
?>
```

I know this example is very rudementary, but I could use some help getting on the right path. I apprecite it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use `session_start()` at the top of each page, without this you cannot read or write any session data.

Once you have done this, you will change session variables in the $_SESSION global.  To set the time try `$_SESSION['time'] = time()`.  This will save the current time in seconds (Unix Timestamp).  To calculate if the time was set greater than an hour ago use this:

```
session_start();
// 60 seconds * 60 minutes = 3600, or 3600 = seconds in an hour
if(time() - $_SESSION['time'] > 3600) {
    // Current time - survey_time is greater than one hour (expired)
    header('Location: /survey/page/url/');
} else {
    // Not expired - do stuff
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Thank you for the help! I got it working now as desired. I moved the session_start() and $_SESSION['time' = time() to a separate file, then in the success handler of my form submission I $.post to that file to start the session, so its only valid AFTER a successful form submission. One final question as there are multiple ajax submits that will start the session, how do I clear all sessions then start a new one?

Comment: @DirtyBirdDesign `session_start()` is a little deceiving, it will start a session or grab an existing session if one exists for that user.  I think by default they expire after 30 minutes of inactivity.  So each page is actually using the same session (for that user).  If you want to force a new session you can use `session_destroy()` (use session_start first) but that's really made for a logout page.  Hopefully that helps!